# Getting items in sql in different tables

Tags: sql

I have the following tables..

**`items`**

```
ID | Title   |       Desc
67 | Title_1 |  Description_1
68 | Title_2 |  Description_2
```

**`tag`**

```
ID |  Name
5  |  tag_1
7  | tag_2
22 | tag_3
23 | tag_4
```

**`tag_ref`**

```
ID  | tagID   | itemID
1   | 5       | 68
2   | 7       | 67
3   | 5       | 67
4   | 23      | 68
5   | 22      | 68
```

Now, I want to select all items with the same tagID with the current product item id = 67

Cause I wanna get the related items by tags.

Comment: have you even tried to solve this problem on your own?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM items JOIN item tag_ref on tag_ref.itemID = items.ID JOIN tag 
on tag.ID = tag_ref.tagID where item.ID = 67
```

Answer (score 0):

Join `items` and `tag_ref`, only returning items where a tagID exists in the subquery that returns all tagIDs for item 67:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items
JOIN tag_ref as t on t.itemID = items.ID
WHERE t.tagID in (SELECT t2.tagID 
                  FROM tag_ref as t2
                  JOIN items as i2 on i2.ID = t2.itemID
                  WHERE i2.ID = 67)
```

Comment: Hi, i have the following. but it doesnt work.. SELECT items.*
FROM #__k2_items as items
JOIN #__k2_tags_xref as t ON t.itemID = items.ID
WHERE t.tagID in (SELECT t2.tagID 
                  FROM #__k2_tags_xref as t2
                  JOIN items as i2 on i2.ID = t2.itemID
                  WHERE i2.ID = 67)

Comment: Try first just running the subquery. Does it return all of the tags for item 67 properly? If so, then assuming that the data is consistent, I don't see why this wouldn't work.